# Passing props from Laravel Blade to Vue.Js return undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I tried to pass props from Laravel blade to Vue element, tried to use:
**:data** or
**data**
both didn't work.

Returns undefined on Vue Devtool.

**file.blade.php**

```
<div id="truthchallenge">
  <truth-challenge data="datastring" />
</div>
```

**truthchallenge.js** (main.js)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from '../router'
import TruthChallenge from './views/TruthChallenge'

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(TruthChallenge)
}).$mount('#truthchallenge')
```

**TruthChallenge.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'truth-challenge',
  props: {
    data: String
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried to pass props from a vue.js  to child, it works, but not from the Laravel blade.
Do you have clues about what doesn't work on my code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to pass php variable into Vue template?

Try it like this:

```
<truth-challenge :data="{{ $data }}"/>
```

Comment: I tried to pass an object. I used "data" (as string) as sample, which should return props value as "data" as well but instead it gives me undefined.